# How do I cancel the upload inside an event?

Tags: symfony, oneupuploaderbundle

I am using Symfony2 with OneUpUploader and I would like to cancel an upload based on some data, can anyone tell me how do I do that from within an event ?

From within PreUploadEvent to be exact. Thanks.

Comment: You can just throw an Exception like they have done in the validation listeners (https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/EventListener/DisallowedMimetypeValidationListener.php)

Comment: Hmm, as brutal as throwing an exception seems, You are probably right, thanks.